# Swift: Seeking advice on accomplishing specific flow between storyboards/viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

So I am working on an app and am finally getting to a point where I am starting to build actual modules instead of playgrounds and utility apps for tests. So I really want to do this right since I am jumping into the real deal right now. I was hoping to get advice that will help me accomplish my goals for the apps "flow" without me hacking something together that will come back to bite me later.

So imagine I have a home screen(a single view controller) that can branch to multiple storyboards. The mechanism I want to trigger transitions is the user grabbing an image on the home screen with their finger, and flicking it off the screen. When the image is no longer on screen, I'd like to transition to a storyboard that corresponds to that image. For instance, the user might flick the "settings" image to open a settings panel.

```
[home storyboard] -- [user flicks image off screen] --> [alternate storyboard]
```

I have already accomplished this kind of, but with the way I am doing it now I am unsure how to be able to navigate back from the second storyboard back to the home storyboard. It also seems unclean and hacky to me.

```
Right now it is set up as such:
    Home is its own storyboard - main.storyboard
    Home contains one simple viewcontroller
    Alt is another storyboard - alt.storyboard
    Alt contains a navigationcontroller
```

How can I facilitate things such that Alt's navigation controller will recognize that it was just in the Home storyboard, so that it will provide a "back" button for navigating back home?

Or, if anyone has any advice as to how I might accomplish this in a neater way, I would greatly appreciate it. I want each "module" (ie alt.storyboard's contents) to be in different storyboards for organizational sake.

Here is the code I use to seque to my second storyboard:

```
if !(recognizer.view!.window == nil)   {
    print("object left window")
    let viewController: UIViewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Alt"))! as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks so much for taking the time to check this out, let me know if I have not been clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

you could put the main viewcontroller (from `Home` storyboard) itself into a navigation controller and simply push the initial viewcontroller from the storyboard you want to reach (in your example `Alt` storyboard) with a custom transition. so the viewcontrollers from all the other storyboards except of `Home` should not be embedded in a navigation controller!

Comment: This is nice and simple, thanks. My problem now is, when I "flick" the image off screen and detect that with the code above, the presentViewController pushing the new view does not cause the new view to inherit the navigation, however, when I point a button from home to a storyboard reference to the new view it does.

How can I create a transition in code so that my event behaves more like the button?

Comment: Okay I was able to fix this issue by telling my navigationcontroller to push a view rather than using presentViewController.

Now if only there was a way to make my image animate back to its original position when the user returned to "home", instead of when they are still in "alt".